# ENOENT (No such file or directory) on database file

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This happens on this line of code:

```
File db = getDatabasePath("questions");
db.createNewFile();//HERE
```

I am trying to create a database file with the name questions.db , which will be empty. I will then pull the file from the server and insert it there. I then want to be able to access the database from sqlite.

Comment: `I am trying to create a database file with the name questions.db` **No**. You are trying to create a database named `questions`: `File db = getDatabasePath("questions");`

Comment: @DerGolem so what can I do about it?

Comment: Instead of `db.createNewFile();`, I do so: `final SQLiteDatabase db =
   ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);` where ctx is a passed Context (the code is in its own class, inside a method)

Comment: @DerGolem I want to pull the questions.db file from a server...

Comment: ... so what? just download it into the right folder. `/data/data/...` (if you want to keep it private - or somewhere on your storage, if it's OK to make it public)

Comment: Do i need to create the database afterwards again?
Where is the correct foldeR?

Comment: No. You don't need to re-create it (it would be then useless to download it, if you overwrite it). The path is (if you want to keep the db private) `/data/data/your.app.name/databases/`. Where `your.app.name` is your complete package name. You can access that path even in the DDMS, to see that everything worked.

Comment: @DerGolem do I still get an ENOENT exception. What do I need to do? call openOrCreateDatabase("questions.db" , ... , ......) ?

Comment: You're probably trying to open the db **before** it has been copied into the path. So, it doesn't find it and gives you the error. Normally you should handle this event. If the db isn't found, copy it. Else open it

Comment: @DerGolem im not doing anything like openorcreate . Just creating the empty file....

Comment: If you call `openOrCreateDatabase("questions.db" , ... , ......);` an empty db will be created. Then check if the length is < 4096 (I use this magic number, but you can use a higher one to determine if the db is empty). If so, copy the db from the assets folder. If not, the db will be open and you can start using it.

Comment: @DerGolem I just need a blank file.

Comment: @user4360138 Did you notice that all your questions are downvoted and you dod not accept a single answer? Please do not only take from this community. Also invest some love (starting with a name).

Answer (score 1):

You did not show the stack trace, it can help to pinpoint it. But since the [File#createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) is not doing much, the only possible reason for this to fail is, that the (relative) path includes a non-existing parent directory. createNewFile() will not create those.

You typically write

```
File db = ...
db.getParentFile().mkdirs();
db.createNewFile();
```

to fix this. (Or use a different - aka existing - location).

Comment: "//HERE"? :) I was talking about the stack details inside the function. However, I cannot imagine any other reason for File#createNewFile() to fail besides a missing parent dir. You can print out `db` to see where it wants to create a file.